# Difficulties in relations in Yii

Tags: php, yii, relational-database

So question is I have `Post` and `User` models 
`Post` one contains - `id, title, body and user_id` fields
`User` contains - `id, name`
So what I need is when post is published, it shows `user_id` field instead of `name` field.
I'm struggling this problem please can you help me what I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check if you have defined relation in Post model - something like this:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id')
    );
}
```

Now you should get post author (user name) in this way:

```
$post->user->name;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've already solved problem myself!

Comment: Then select this option as an answer